why this rule is not valid for the following $\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{(e^n)}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$?
We know $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =\frac{ \lim_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a} g(x)}.$ I'm provided $n ≠ 0$
Then why this rule is not valid for the following $\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{(e^n)}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is not true that  $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x)}{\lim g(x)}$. It is only true if    $\lim f(x)=A$, $\lim g(x)=B$ where $A,B$ are finite  and $B≠0$. In your case  $e^n$ diverge to $+\infty$ so the theorem doesn't hold anymore.

@Antares oh I got it

It is not applied here directly because it's of no use here. For example,you can't apply the limit provided to $e^n$ which is the numerator, as it individually tends to infinity. You need to first simplify the expression.
$$f(n)= \frac{e^n}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^  {n^2}}=\frac{e^n}{e^{n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}}=e^{n-n^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}$$
(Above I have used $x=e^{\ln x}$ in the denominator)
By Taylor series,
$$ \ln \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^3}\bigg)$$
Applying limits to $f(n)$ ,
$$\lim_{n \to ∞} e^{n-n^2\bigg[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^3}\bigg)\bigg]}$$
As $n→∞,O(\frac{1}{n^3})→0$. Hence
$$=\lim_{n→∞} e^{n-n+\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{n→∞} e^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt e$$
